# How can I create a week selector for a specific day of the week?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking to create a week selector, which only displays Mondays on the calendar.

Like:

January (2024):
1 8 15 22 29

February (2024):
5 12 19 26

etc...

Found `react-date-range` library, but it seems it doesn't provide such functionality. May be you can suggest some other lib to achieve this?

So far I tried to use dayContentRenderer to "exclude" unneeded days, but it still does displays every day of a month.

```
<DateRangePicker
        staticRanges={[]}
        inputRanges={[]}
        ranges={[selectionRange]}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        onChange={this.handleSelect}
        dayContentRenderer={(date: Date) => { return date.getDay() === 1 ? <span>{date.getDay()}</span> : null;}}
      />
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would suggest adding some code asking for a library won't solve your action try to implement it then post what did u try and what went wrong

Comment: I can implement it from scratch of course. And that's what I'll do, unless find a more or less ready solution to save time of styling and extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is an awesome library, it has a function called eachWeekOfInterval which returns an array of dates and takes option to choose which day the week starts on

```js
eachWeekOfInterval(
  {
    start: startDate,
    end: endDate,
  },
  { weekStartsOn: 1 }
)
```